# Burp suite: cannot intercept traffic from a docker image application

Tags: docker, proxy, burp

There is a Juice Shop vulnerable application, which is available as a docker image. I am testing it on Windows 10.
I was able to run the application with the following commands:

```
docker pull bkimminich/juice-shop
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 bkimminich/juice-shop
```

Now Burp does not allow to set a listener on 127.0.0.1:3000, presumably because the docker
is listening on that port. I cannot check the running option on the proxy listeners.

If I check the listener on Burp first, then the docker run fails with:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 bkimminich/juice-shop
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint stupefied_poincare (003588db40943cf7607c7c5dc20ad9f51eaef7bc81c7cf470fa6a2d20fcbd398): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:3000: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to start Burp with different `Port` and setup docker to use that as a `proxy` in your `~/.docker/config.json` file:

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://THEHOSTIPFORBURP:3001"
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: After I have set up the docker proxy, I did not have errors, but the Burp is not intercepting. With docker proxy setup, the app should be still started wit `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 bkimminich/juice-shop`, right?

Comment: Yes I did restart it.

Comment: check if the container reached the proxy or make some request inside the conatiner and see if burp can see them

Comment: you can also try to add this to your docker run command `--env HTTP_PROXY "http://127.0.0.1:3001"`

Comment: I am on Windows, the `--env` option is not there. Maybe I try on Linux later. Concerning the request inside the container, I get this error:
`/juice-shop $ wget localhost:3000`
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3001 (127.0.0.1:3001)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
The shop is built on Alpine Linux, where the tools are rudimentary.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error. `/juice-shop $ wget 172.17.0.2:3000`
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3001 (127.0.0.1:3001)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused

Comment: OK, got it working. Thanks. The solution was to set up the HTTP proxy for Docker. (I forgot to set proxy settings on Firefox.)